# CSS: how to align text content horizontally-centered and vertically-centered?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, alignment

how can i align text content inside div horizonally-centered and vertically-centered?

```
   <div style="height: 300px;">
     <p>Envision various details for your big day with help from our photo catalog, which features images filtered by category. See actual works from suppliers to help you make decisions.</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: see this link you might get something.....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073594/vertically-and-horizontally-centering-container-and-content-in-container

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430831/vertically-and-horizontally-centering-text-within-a-div

Comment: Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content" http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: hi all, answer from @mr.alien make it works. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` properties with `text-align: center;` as well to align the text vertically and horizontally centered

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hfsXr/)

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```